# Making Operational Layer from WebTiledLayer and MapImage?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer

I'm attempting to use the CMV and put a WebTiled layer in as an operational layer.  I've been able to get the layer into the basemap without issue, but can't get sort it out for the Operational Layer.  I'm trying the same thing for a MapImage, it works in a basic viewer and not with the syntax in viewer.js.  Any suggestions on where to begin would be excellent.

```
    //Working code as a basemap
mapboxPirates: {
        title: 'Pirates (mapbox)',
        basemap: new Basemap({
            id: 'mapboxPirates',
            layers: [new BasemapLayer({
                url: "http://${subDomain}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/aj.Sketchy2/${level}/${col}/${row}.png",
                copyright: "mapbox, 2015",
                id: "mapboxPirates",
                subDomains: ["a","b","c","d"],
                type:"WebTiledLayer"
                })]
        })
}

    //An operational layer mapimage that doesn't work
    {
  type: 'mapimage',
  title: 'radar',
  id: 'radar',
  options:{
      extent: { xmin: -8864908, ymin: 3885443, xmax: -8762763, ymax: 3976997, spatialReference: { wkid: 102100 }},
      href: 'http://localhost/goes_ecan_1070_100.jpg',
    visible: true,
  }
}

    //Operational Web tiled that doesn't work
    {
  type: 'tiled',
  title: 'The Web Tiled',
  id: 'theTiled',
  urlTemplate: 'http://{subDomain}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/vx/map/{level}/{col}/{row}.jpg',
  options: {
    copyright: "MapQuest © 2012",
    subDomains: ["mtile01", "mtile02", "mtile03", "mtile04"],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the [layer types](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/blob/master/viewer/js/viewer/Controller.js#L227) that CMV currently supports. From there you can see that the layer type `mapimage` is still untested so it may not work at all. If you do get it to work or if a change to CMV is required, please submit an issue or preferably a Pull Request at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app).

The layer type `tiled` is not valid for a web tiled layer. That type is used for a ArcGISTiledMapService layer. Unfortunately, web tiled layers are not currently supported only because no one has added that type yet. I will look into adding this in a future release. If you get it working before that future release, a Pull Request with working code would be greatly appreciated. :)